# Does Cassandra make any outbound connections (other than peer to peer connections)

Tags: cassandra

I am wondering if Cassandra would be a good database for a disconnected use case to act as our data store solution. I'm wondering if cassandra makes any outbound connections to the outside world during initialization, operation, or shut down.

Thanks for the help!